# Change table stroke thickness using swatches in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, swatches

I am currently creating a large table and I would like to quickly be able to change the thickness of the borders to see what looks best. It is possible to quickly change the color of multiple items by changing the swatch they are colored with, but is there an equivalent for thickness? Or can you add thickness into swatches? Currently the only way I can change the table is by painstakingly selecting cells and changing it manually. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the paths. Then use `Select > Save Selection`.

This will allow you to choose that saved selection and then alter them all at once easily.

Another option is to color one cell and then create a **Graphic Style**. Apply that Graphic Style to all cells. You can then select one cell, alter it, and then drag it over the existing Graphic Style, hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> and drop the new cell on top of the old graphic style. Everything with that style will be updated.

And another option is to use **Symbols**. Create a symbol of a single cell. Place additional Symbol Instances for other cells. You can then double click the symbol to edit it and all instances will update.